# Do all nuclear Frechet spaces have Schauder basis?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

When I read an article recently, I see this statement as a conjecture.
So I want to ask, do all nuclear Frechet space have Schauder basis?
Is this still open? Or has been solved? I’ll appreciate any comments or references you give. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The answer to the question in your title is negative (Mitiagin, Zobin, 1974).

Comment: @ifatfirstyoudontsucceed Thanks a lot!

Comment: Moreover, Djakov–Mitiagin (1976) construct a nuclear Fréchet space X such that for any nuclear Fréchet space Y the space X⨯Y has no basis.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov Thanks a lot!